# What does negative index mean in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

Recently I read a R statement somewhere, which said:

```
mtcars[-1]
```

What does -1 imply here? I do understand the following statement:

```
mtcars[1]
```

which means select the first column from the data frame, but I just could not infer the negative sign in the index?

Comment: `mtcars[-1]` mean *all but the first column* of the `mtcars` dataframe

Comment: See the comment by [Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074119/r-programming-query) posted today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minus means remove the element with that index, just like "no minus" extract that element with the index